# Download page html and css in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

It is possible, in C #, download a complete html page, ie, in addition to obtain the html page that also get the css page?

Answer (score 4):

I could suggest two solutions:

1. If this is possible in your project you can use Internet Explorer through automation to load this page and save it. Here is a good example - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2847/Automated-IE-SaveAs-MHTML. It is not .NET based but the idea is the same
2. Another option is to download HTML manually (e.g. using WebClient object) and parse it to find CSS and JavaScript references. There are some third party libraries that can help you with this, for example, the [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net).

Answer (score 1):

You can easily accomplish this with the `WebClient` object, e.g.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string reply = client.DownloadString (address);
```

[WebClient.DownloadString Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

In order to grab an external CSS file, you'd need to examine the HTML and extract the CSS URI.  Then you could simply call, for instance,

```
client.DownloadString ("http://www.example.com/somecss.css");
```

Comment: this will only get the html, css still missing

Comment: It was just an example, presumably you could call it multiple times to download additional content.

Comment: But this example I already knew, thanks to the same

Comment: @Kiotto you should edit your question to exclude answers you've already tried and rejected. It'll help you get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can get the whole page and parse out the CSS links inside the html:

```
using (var web = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    web.DownloadFile(_source, _destination);
}
```

Comment: this will only get the html, css still missing

Comment: yes, you will have to parse the html for that, either CSS itself or the link of the CSS file and again download the CSS file like you did the HTML file. You will have to do it yourself, I'm not payed to help you write the code you were supossed to do yourself, this help is voluntary